# Move from Opencart to Magento - Category url structure not matching

Tags: magento-1.9, category, url, canonical

When moving from Opencart to Magento I have encountered a big issue.

**Open cart shop has this structure:**

*example.com/barnvagnar/bugaboo/bugaboo-buffalo*

*example.com/barnvagnar/bugaboo-buffalo*

*example.com/bugaboo-buffalo*

All urls are for the exact same category. None has rel canonical (which they should have). *example.com/bugaboo-buffalo* is the url that is ranking high in Google.

**On the new Magento 1.9.x site we only have one url for this category:**
*example.com/barnvagnar/bugaboo/bugaboo-buffalo*

**Question:** 
How can I get both *example.com/barnvagnar/bugaboo/bugaboo-buffalo* and *example.com/bugaboo-buffalo* to work on Magento? With correct rel cononical to *example.com/bugaboo-buffalo*. I really need the example.com/bugaboo-buffalo to work for SEO purposes. I really want to avoid to do a 301 redirect.

Basically I need this

```
- Root-Category (URL: /rootcategory )

-- Sublevel category (both has to work) --> /sublevelcategory
-- Sublevel category (both has to work) --> /rootcategory/sublevelcategory
```

Is there a built in setting for this in the Magento backend configuration?